# plotly express scatter_3d error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' but input is valid numpy array

Tags: plotly

I have an array as follows:

```
array(\[\[-0.35262136, -0.05299355, -0.40123576\],
\[-0.11963161,  0.37991197, -0.26190565\],
\[-0.20608609,  0.59781661,  0.073084  \],
\[-0.42654284,  0.0283985 , -0.09368208\],
\[ 0.216713  , -0.14491763,  0.38559991\],
\[ 0.37343351, -0.12512076,  0.21548315\],
\[ 0.18497163, -0.3841585 ,  0.12596435\],
\[ 0.32976376, -0.29893663, -0.04330791\]\])
```

I want to plot it with plotly express scatter_3d.

```
pcoa_plot = px.scatter_3d(X_transform, x=0,y=1,z=2, width=1000, height=1000,color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet, title="Beta Diversity Plot (Bray-Curtis)")
```

I get this error:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

The array should be valid input to this function however and this code was working in the past. Seems broken now. Can anyone suggest what to do?> Thanks - Robert

The array should be valid input to this function however and this code was working in the past. Seems broken now. Can anyone suggest what to do?> Thanks - Robert